# navigationcontroller back to upper navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

The question is show in the picture. How can I back from viewcontroller C to A.
Method popViewControllerAnimated doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue in your controllers hierarchy. You shouldn't have an `UINavigationController` between your `UIViewController` A and C.

Since the `UITabBarController` push the controller A embedded in an `UINavigationController`, your navigation is already setup for this tab, no need to repush another one later.

So, to solve your issue, you should have that for the first tab: UITabBarViewController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController A -> UIViewController C. This way, the `popViewControllerAnimated` will work.